# Decoding string using HtmlDecode or Escape

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization, xml-deserialization

EDIT - Modified based on the answer:

okay here is what I modified based on the answer:

here is the string.

```
"November is Fruit&#39;s Fresh."
```

here is what I'm doing:

```
    static string EscapeCharacters(string txt)
    {
        string encodedTxt = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(txt);
        return HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(encodedTxt);
    }

    string _decodedTxt = EscapeCharacters("November is Fruit&#39;s Fresh.");
```

when it returns I'm still getting the same text `November is Fruit&#39;s Fresh.`

**END EDIT**

I tried using `HttpUtility.HtmlDecode` from `System.Web` and also tried using `SecurityElement.Escape` but it does not escapes anything correctly.

so I end-up writing my own replace method something like this:

```
    static string EscapeXMLCharacters(string txt)
    {
        string _txt = txt.Replace("&amp;", "&").Replace("&lt;", "<").Replace("&gt;", ">").Replace("&quot;", "\"").Replace("&apos;", "'").Replace("&#38;", "&").Replace("&#60;", "<").Replace("&#62;", ">").Replace("&#34;", "\\").Replace("&#39;", "'");
        return _txt;
    }
```

it does work in my situation but its hard to cover everything and in my situation I have some European characters like ``` í``(&#237;) ``` or `é (&#233;)`

Is there a utility method built-in .Net that take cares of any special characters?

Comment: try HTMLAgilityPack - http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `HtmlEncode` to encode the string and then you can use `HtmlDecode` to return the original value:

```
string x = "éí&";
string encoded = System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(x);
Console.WriteLine(encoded);  //&#233;&#237;&amp;

string decoded = System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(encoded);
Console.WriteLine(decoded);  //éí&
```

With your update, you just need to decode the string:

```
String decoded = System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode("November is Fruit&#39;s Fresh.");
Console.WriteLine(decoded);   //November is Fruit's Fresh.
```

Comment: I updated my question, I'm still getting the encoded value even though i encode and decode, please see my question.

Comment: @AbuHamzah See my update, but for this case, you just need to decode it.

Comment: Thanks and I have another string with `&amp;amp;` is that even valid? this is driving me crazy and it should not be that difficult but looks like the data i am getting is bad?

Comment: `&amp;amp;` is `&` encoded twice.  If you decoded it twice, you would probably get the expected result.

Answer (score 1):

tagText = SecurityElement.Escape(tagText);

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.securityelement.escape.aspx

or

```
 System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode(textContent);
```